# $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] become empty if the url change

Tags: php

I have a problem to resolve. The first url allow me to display information or not on the website. It work fine.
I identify Account&Edit for example and make action.

```
http://localhost/boutique/index.php?Account&Edit
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] = Account&Edit
```

If I rewrite the url, the system does not work and Account&Edit become Account/Edit

```
http://localhost/boutique/index.php/Account/Edit
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] = '';
```

How to resolve this element when this element Account&Edit change ?
`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is empty is this case.

Thank you.

I make that to solve the problem.

```
public function getUrlwithoutSEFU() {
  if (empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $replace = str_replace('index.php', '', $url);
    $replace = str_replace(CLICSHOPPING::getConfig('http_path'), '', $replace);
    $replace = substr($replace, 1);
    $replace = str_replace('/', '&', $replace);
    $url_string = $replace;
  } else {
    $url_string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }

  return $url_string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [RFC3875: The Common Gateway Interface (CGI) Version 1.1](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875)

- When you have no `?` i nthe request URL, then there's no query string.
- Looking at `REQUEST_URI` would make sense.

This is how request urls are split into environment vars:

```
#                                   QUERY_STRING
#                                   ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
http://localhost/boutique/index.php?Account&Edit
```

Or the part after the (directly invoked) php script. (This may vary depending on SAPI or be impacted by rewrite rules).

```
#                                    PATH_INFO
#                                  ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
http://localhost/boutique/index.php/Account/Edit
```

Or the full path:

```
#                        REQUEST_URI
#               ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
http://localhost/boutique/index.php/Account/Edit
```

Notably you would have to split it up yourself then. Also may show up as `REDIRECT_REQUEST_URI` for example in the `$_SERVER` array with some setups.

Comment: tk, look above, I wrote a function

Comment: You can post it as answer later, if you think that function is useful to other people. But don't add it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
public function getUrlwithoutSEFU() {
  if (empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $replace = str_replace('index.php', '', $url);
    $replace = str_replace(CLICSHOPPING::getConfig('http_path'), '', $replace);
    $replace = substr($replace, 1);
    $replace = str_replace('/', '&', $replace);
    $url_string = $replace;
  } else {
    $url_string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }

  return $url_string;
}
```